# Country committee from A first course in Probability (1.30)

Tags: combinatorics

The exercise says as it follows:

> Delegates from 10 countries, including Russia, France, England, and the United States, are to be seated in a row. How many different seating arrangements are possible if the French and English delegates are to be seated next to each other and the Russian and U.S. delegates are not to be next to each other?

To solve the problem, I initially reduce the amount of the total by 1 since England and France always go together (then multiply by 2 the result to consider each of the permutations of the 2 countries).

I am not sure how can I introduce the constraint of Russia and US not sitting together.

Comment: It's easier to work backwards.  Figure out the total number with England/France together, then subtract those which also have Russia/USA together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [comment from @lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841782/country-committee-from-a-first-course-in-probability-1-30#comment10312625_4841782) this problem is easily solved. The procedure is the following:

- Firstly, calculate which are the cases in which England and France are together. Join England and France into a block and calculate the number of combinations with the new possible entities ($9!$). Then, multiply by the number of possible permutations within the England-France block ($2!$). This gives a total of $9!2!$.
- Then calculate the cases where England and France go as a block and EEUU and Russia too (8!). Each of the blocks give additional $2!$ combinations, therefore the total is $8!2!2!$.
- Subtract the second result from the first one.

[Link to the Inclusion-Exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) (wasn't familiarized with this name).